# Error in calculation: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, integer, point, multiplication

I had to write this Python code as a project in my Logic class.  I've almost finished it, but when I try it, I get this error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>

    opay = [(maxhrs - hworked) *orate] * prate

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`
What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Here is the code I have now:

```
while True:
    cname = 'My Company'
    drate = .17
    maxhrs = 40
    pdate = "9/1/2015"
    orate = 1.5
    lc = 'Y'

while(lc == 'Y'):
    ename = raw_input("Enter employee's name.")
    dcode = raw_input("Enter department code.(1 - Shipping 2 - Mngmt.)")
    hworked = float(raw_input("Enter total hours worked."))
    prate = float(raw_input("Enter your pay rate."))
    inscost = float(raw_input("Enter the cost of insurance."))
    city = float(raw_input("Enter your city code.(1 - Sumiton 2 - Hamilton)"))
    st = raw_input("Enter your state")
    sex = raw_input("Enter your sex.(M - Male F - Female)")
    yrsemp = raw_input("Enter total years employed.")

print("Welcome to our company: ", cname)
print("Pay period date: ", pdate)

if(sex == 'M'):
    sexword = 'Male'
else:
    sexword = 'Female'
print("Employee name: ", ename, "Sex: ", sexword)

if(city == '1'):
    cityn = 'Sumiton'
else:
    cityn = 'Hamilton'
print("City: ", cityn, "State: ", state)

if(dcode == '1'):
    dname = 'Shipping'
else:
    dname = 'Management'
print("Department name: ", dname)

rpay = maxhrs * prate
print("Regular pay: ", rpay)
opay = [(maxhrs - hworked) * orate] * prate
print("Overtime pay: ", opay)
gross = rpay + opay
print("Gross before deduction: ", gross)
damt = drate * gross
print("Deduction amount: ", damt "Insurance cost: ", inscost)
npay = gross - (damt + icost)
print("Net pay: ", npay)
new = raw_input("Would you like to start over with a new person? yes/no")
if(new = 'yes')

restart = int(input("Press 1 to try again, 0 to exit. "))
if(restart == '1'):
    continue
elif(restart == '0'):
    break
else:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter 1 to restart or 0 to exit.")
```

Comment: `opay = [(maxhrs - hworked) *orate] * prate` <-- what are you trying to do here? I think you may have meant `opay = ((maxhrs - hworked) *orate) * prate`.. `()` and `[]` are not interchangeable in python.

Answer (score -1):

In Python 3.0, the 2.x input() function, which evaluates the string, was

> removed, and the 2.x raw_input() function, which just returns the string 
>   that was entered, was renamed to input().
>
> Is there any special function that I should add in order to work
>
> > properly under Python 3.0?
>
> x = int(input('x:maxhrs ')) 
>   y = int(input('y:hworked '))